# Clojure Lazy Sequence Issue

Tags: clojure

I'm working on 4clojure problems and a similar issue keeps coming up. I'll write a solution that works for all but one of the test cases. It's usually the one that is checking for lazy evaluation. The solution below works for all but the last test case.  I've tried all kinds of solutions and can't seem to get it to stop evaluating until integer overflow. I read the chapter on lazy sequences in Joy of Clojure, but I'm having a hard time implementing them. Is there a rule of thumb I'm forgetting, like don't use loop or something like that?

```
; This version is non working at the moment, will try to edit a version that works
(defn i-between [p k coll]
  (loop [v [] coll coll]
     (let [i (first coll) coll (rest coll) n (first coll)]
        (cond (and i n)
          (let [ret (if (p i n) (cons k (cons i v)) (cons i v))]
            (recur ret coll))
          i
          (cons i v )
        :else  v))))
```

[Problem 132](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/132)

Ultimate solution for those curious:

```
(fn i-between [p k coll]
  (letfn [(looper [coll]
     (if (empty? coll) coll
       (let [[h s & xs] coll 
          c (cond (and h s (p h s))
                   (list h k )
                  (and h s)
                   (list h )
                  :else (list h))]
          (lazy-cat c (looper (rest coll))))
   ))] (looper coll)))
```

Comment: There are two ways to make a lazy-seq: call the `lazy-seq` function, or call a function that calls it.

Comment: if I use lazy-cat and wrap it, it still doesn't evaluate lazy.  it goes until the whole thing overflows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I think about lazy sequences, what usually works is thinking about incremental `cons'ing`

That is, each recursion step only adds *a single* element to the list, and of course you never use `loop`.

So what you have is something like this:

```
(cons (generate first) (recur rest))
```

When wrapped on `lazy-seq`, only the needed elements from the sequence are realized, for instance.

```
 (take 5 (some-lazy-fn))
```

Would only do `5` recursion calls to realize the needed elements.

A tentative, far from perfect solution to the `4clojure` problem, that demonstrates the idea:

```
(fn intercalate 
  [pred value col]
  (letfn [(looper [s head]
            (lazy-seq 
              (if-let [sec (first s)]
                (if (pred head sec)
                  (cons head (cons value (looper (rest s) sec)))
                  (cons head (looper (rest s) sec)))
               (if head [head] []))))]
    (looper (rest col) (first col))))
```

There, the local recursive function is `looper`, for each element tests if the predicate is `true`, in that case realizes two elements(adds the interleaved one), otherwise realize just one.

Also, you can avoid recursion using higher order functions

```
(fn [p v xs]
   (mapcat
    #(if (p %1 %2) [%1 v] [%1])
    xs
    (lazy-cat (rest xs) (take 1 xs))))
```

But as @noisesmith said in the comment, you're just calling a function that calls `lazy-seq`.

Comment: Your second solution adds a `:less` on the end (not inserted _between_ anything) for `(__ < :less [1 2 3 2 1 0])`.

Comment: I know, but it passes the tests and was good enough an alternative example without recursion.

Comment: The advice to never use `for` is baseless: `for` is lazy, and is frequently a perfect component of a lazy-seq-producing function. For example, I don't think `for` is the most readable choice here, but https://gist.github.com/amalloy/72d98ff89b7ffe665df5 is my solution to this 4clojure problem, modified slightly to use `for` instead of `mapcat`.

Comment: By the way, `(cons a (cons b xs))` is better written as `(list* a b xs)`: `list*` is just a series of calls to `cons`.